# Possible to stop API call on ReferenceInput with AutocompleteInput

Tags: react-admin

I have a ReferenceInput with an AutocompleteInput, and I don't want it to make another API call when I choose an input.

```
<ReferenceInput
  label="Message Code"
  reference="plan"
  source="msgCode"
>
  <AutocompleteInput optionValue="msgCode" optionText="msgCode"/>
</ReferenceInput>
```

React-Admin gets the list of Plans here, and I want to pass the plan.msgCode as the optionValue and optionText.

But when I make a selection, it makes an API call to /plan/{msgCode} (even though the list of Plans already has all the details I need, and my API doesn't support this kind of route.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

That behavior is not possible to disable (v 3.8.4) or bypass in any kind.
Maybe in feature versions this option will be available but for now, if your API can't support this feature, i would recommend to avoid using this component.

Version: react-admin@3.8.4